# In Xamarin forms, how do I pass a child collection to a new page to be used in a listview if already coming from a parent listview?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

So here's the scenario.  I have a parent listview whose Model contains another collection I'd like to pass over to another page to be used in another list view upon clicking a label.

Parent ViewModel is as follows:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Songs> JazzCollection { get; set; }
    public RecordsViewModel()
    {
        JazzCollection = new ObservableCollection<Songs>();
        var playlist = new Songs
        {
            Station = "Jazz Legends",
            Artists = new ObservableCollection<Artist>
            {
                new Artist
                {
                    ArtistID = 0,
                    Name = "John Coltrane",
                    Song = "Giant Steps"
                },
                new Artist
                {
                    ArtistID = 1,
                    Name = "Miles Davis",
                    Song = "So What"
                },
                new Artist
                {
                    ArtistID = 2,
                    Name = "Blue Mitchell",
                    Song = "Kinda Blue"
                },
            },
            Title = "Click here to see artists in playlist"
        };
        JazzCollection.Add(playlist);

        var anotherPlaylist
            .
            .
            .
        JazzCollection.Add(anotherPlaylist);
    }
```

Now the parent XAML is:

```
<ListView x:Name="RecordsListView"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          HasUnevenRows="true"
          ItemsSource="{Binding JazzCollection}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Station}"/>
                    <!--WHEN THEY CLICK ON THIS TITLE BELOW
                        I'D LIKE THEM TO GO TO A NEW PAGE LISTING
                        THE ARTISTS IN THIS STATION. HOW DO I
                        BIND THE ARTISTS ObservableCollection TO
                        THE NEW PAGE? -->
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The listview displays the parent with no issues but I'm having difficulty sending over the child collection "Artists" to be used as the BindingContext in a new page.  Any ideas how to do this?

Here's what I was planning on doing for the new page Viewmodel but I'm not sure it's right.

```
public class ArtistViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public ArtistViewModel(ObservableCollection<Artist> artists)
    {
        Artists = artists;
    }
}
```

Then I'd use "Artists" as the ItemSource in the new ListView on second page.

Comment: Depends how you are creating your view model on the new page, or what frame works you are using and  viewcontructors

Comment: @Saruman I edited the post addressing what you asked.

Comment: Are you just using pushasync to open the new pages?

Comment: @Saruman yes.  That's the plan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be a TapGestureRecognizer but a few other things needed to be included in the Command for it to work correctly because it's contained within a ListView.  It should look something like this:

```
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer
            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TapCommand, Source={x:Reference JazzCollection}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Comments}"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

One thing to note, x:Reference JazzCollection refers to the name given to the ContentPage.  Had to add this to the top level XML tags: x:Name="JazzCollection".  Here's the link that had the answer I used as a reference.  See comment by JamesMontemagno about 10 comments down.

References:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57539/listview-with-mvvm-tapgesturerecognizer-not-working

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/

Answer (score 1):

add an `ItemSelected` handler to your `ListView`

```
void OnSelection (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.SelectedItem == null) {
    return; //ItemSelected is called on deselection, which results in SelectedItem being set to null
  }

  // get the selected Songs object
  var songs = (Songs)e.SelectedItem;

  // pass the Artists collection to the next page
  Navigation.PushAsync(new ArtistsPage(songs.Artists));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help! We're almost there. That works if I want the navigation to happen upon clicking the entire ListView item. I want the action to happen when I click the "Title" label ONLY as I'm eventually going to make the Station label clickable as well and I'd like it to go to a separate page. Thoughts?

Comment: you would have to attach a TapGestureRecognizer to the Label and pass in a context.  Just using a Button would probably be much easier - then you could pass the context in the CommandParameter

Comment: Thank you @Jason. I'm currently tinkering with that.  Would you by chance be able to post an Answer with an example please?  I'll work on it as well and post if I get it working.
`<Label x:Name="Title" Text={Binding Title}>
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Command="{Binding CommentTapCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label> `

Comment: what you're doing should work.  Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: Nothing happened when you clicked on it because it was in a listview.  The way I posted earlier only works outside of a ListView.  Will post Answer and reference to solution.  Thank you for your help!  You provided valuable hints.